# How can I verify git argument @{u} is working correctly?

Tags: git, flutter

I'm having problems with `flutter upgrade`, which uses:

```
D:\personal-dev\flutter>git rev-parse --verify @{u}
fatal: Needed a single revision
```

However, this works:

```
D:\personal-dev\flutter>git rev-parse --verify origin/stable
78910062997c3a836feee883712c241a5fd22983
```

Any ideas on how I could produce more diagnostic info?

Comment: Your branch somehow has multiple upstream branches?

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED!

Turns out, my commands were executed by cygwin git, not 'normal Windows git', even thought the desired git appeared 1st in the PATH.

Uninstalling just the git package from cygwin fixed it.

Comment: Curious. Was the cygwin Git way out of date? `@{u}` should work the same in any Git that supports it...

Comment: @torek maybe, didn't check. It was installed about 2 years ago. I have no idea how fast git or cygwin git change.